# Counting the number of repeated elements in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Controller:

```
@user_location = Country.joins(:user).order(:name).compact.uniq
```

View (haml):

```
- @user_location.each do |user|
  %li= user.name
```

At this point, all duplicate elements of the array are deleted (`uniq`).

How can I display the number of repetitive elements in the array? For example: if my array has

> One Two Two Three Four

then I need to show

> One Two (2) Three Four

Comment: This seems like a simple algorithm question.  Have you made any attempts yet?

Comment: What's a repetitive element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that something like this might work:

```
# in the controller (this returns a hash)
@locations = Country.joins(:user).order(:name).group(:name).count

# in your view
- @locations.each do |name, count|
  %li
    = name
    = "(#{count})" if count > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `group_by` + `map`. Like this:

```
array.group_by(&:itself).map do |k, v|
 { value: k, count: v.length }
end
```

You will have array of hashes like this: `{value: 'Two', count: 2}`.

You can return data in any desired way. However, it's much better to get grouped records directly from SQL.

Comment: Oo very nice: +1

Comment: You might want to replace `group_by{ |x| x}` with `group_by(&:itself)` to improve readability

Comment: I was wondering what that shorthand looked like @spickermann. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You could even directly map the output as `v > 1 ? "#{k} (#{v})" : k`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through using [each_with_object](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object), counting elements as they're assigned to a hash key. For example:

```
array = %w(One Two Two Three Four)

counts = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |el, hash| 
  hash[el] += 1
end
# => {"One"=>1, "Two"=>2, "Three"=>1, "Four"=>1}

counts.map { |k, v| v > 1 ? "#{k} (#{v})" : k }
# => ["One", "Two (2)", "Three", "Four"]
```

Does that look like what you're after? If not, or you've any questions, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

```
%w[One Two Two Three Four].
  group_by{|x|x}.
  map{|k, v|[k,v.count>1?" (#{v.count})":nil]}.
  map(&:compact).
  map(&:join)
#⇒ ["One", "Two (2)", "Three", "Four"]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes feel free to edit this answer as you wish. I am positive it’s self-explanatory for any future reader who has a base understanding of ruby syntax.